How to achieve this skew effect with curves? (Affinity Designer)
In Affinity Designer, I am trying to skew an object, that is still in curves, however the one corner after certain point turns into additional edge (see picture below).
I want to achieve something that looks like the example in the middle, which I achieved by converting the object to raster and then skewing...


The segments are strokes with no fill. They still obey their selected stroke cap and join options. An example:

There's a stroke-only shape before and after applying skew. No workaround exists if the shapes must be stroke-only.
Use strokeless rectangles as your building blocks. Or apply Layer > Expand Stroke. Do it  before inserting the skew. Two examples:

The grey version has separate rectangles. The red one is combined to one with Boolean ADD before inserting the skew. As well the leftmost red version could be expanded strokes.

Thank you! Expand stroke was what I was looking for.

Clearly the end caps and mitres of the stroke are the issue here. Only the path is being skewed.
You will probably have to convert/expand the stroke to paths, i.e. paths with a fill and no stroke.  I'm not an Affinity Design user, but the same is generally true in other vector software.
Another possible workaround in some software is to skew transform a group, say a stroked path plus an invisible bounding rectangle, then skewing will work properly on the stroke without having to resort to converting/expanding strokes to paths. I'd be surprised if this doesn't also work in Affinity designer. Perhaps try it and see.
